# Responsive table rows, cross browser support with inline-block

Tags: html, css, html-table, cross-browser

I have found MANY examples of how to modify a table to be more responsive, and have applied a few of these suggestions to a text page I have created.

**The problem, as usual, is one of cross-browser support:**

- Works beautifully in Firefox
- If I keep the cells left-aligned, the table works in IE.
- Does not work at all in Chrome nor Safari.

Is there a known issue with Chrome and Safari when using "display: inline-block;" on table cell TDs?  It seems to be ignoring that style.

I know that using a div grid (like Skeleton) is preferable, but we have a bunch of legacy table source code that are mostly used for laying out an old-style grid (as opposed to tabular data).

We were considering applying this class to allow it to at least collapse gracefully until we had time to replace all of the html.

You can see the demo here:
http://www.seanmurray.net/tabletest/

Here is the code for my current demo:

```
<style>
  /****************************/
  /* Responsive Table classes */
  /****************************/
  .rTable {
    display:         table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  .rTable td, .rTable th {
    display:   inline-block;
    overflow:  hidden;
    min-width: calc(100%/5);
    /* VARIABLE:  the #5 is based on how many columns you pick */
    float:     left;
  }
  .rTable, .rTable td, .rTable th, .rTable tr, .rTable tbody  {
    border:  none;
    padding: 0;
    margin:  0;
  }

  /*************************************************************************/
  /*  These styles are for display purposes only-NOT needed for responsive */
  /*************************************************************************/
  .rTable tr {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  }
  .rTable td:nth-child(even) div, .rTable th:nth-child(even) div {
    background-color: #B0C4DE;
  }
  .rTable td:nth-child(odd) div, .rTable th:nth-child(odd) div {
    background-color: #778899;
  }
  .rTable td > div {
    border:  1px solid #999999;

    padding: 2px;

    margin:  2px;
  }
</style>

<hr />

<h2>Responsive table</h2>
This text precedes the table...
<table class="rTable rCenterTable">
  <tr>
    <td><div>Head Row1</div></td>
    <td><div>Head Row2</div></td>
    <td><div>Head Row3</div></td>
    <td><div>Head Row4</div></td>
    <td><div>Head Row5</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>Col1 row1</div></td>
    <td><div>Col2 row1</div></td>
    <td><div>Col3 row1</div></td>
    <td><div>Col4-row1</div></td>
    <td><div>Col5-row1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>Column1-row2</div></td>
    <td><div>Column2-row2</div></td>
    <td><div>Column3-row2</div></td>
    <td><div>Column4-row2</div></td>
    <td><div>Column5-row2</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>C1-r3</div></td>
    <td><div>C2-r3</div></td>
    <td><div>C3-r3</div></td>
    <td><div>C4-r3</div></td>
    <td><div>C5-r3</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>Column1-row4</div></td>
    <td><div>Column2-row4</div></td>
    <td><div>Column3-row4</div></td>
    <td><div>Column4-row4</div></td>
    <td><div>Column5-row4</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>This is Column1, Row5</div></td>
    <td><div>This is Column2, Row5</div></td>
    <td><div>This is Column3, Row5</div></td>
    <td><div>This is Column4, Row5</div></td>
    <td><div>This is Column5, Row5</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
This text follows the table...

<hr />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove float left form .rTable td, .rTable, then it will be fine